# Java File.canRead() hangs forever with bad NFS mount

Tags: java, nfs

I have a Java process trying to read a file over an NFS mount.
I check with `File.canRead()` before I try to read it.
On this occasion the mount is in a bad state.
You can see this with the command line too: both "ls" and "df" hang forever.

`File.canRead()` is hanging forever, and I would really rather have a timeout and log an error than have my process hang forever. What is the ideal way in Java to check that a file can be read without the risk of hanging?

I did a thread-dump and saw

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.canRead(File.java:768)
```

Comment: Do you get different results with `Files.isReadable(file.toPath())`?

Comment: I don't have the ability to test that at the moment (the mount is currently in a good state and I am not sure how to reproduce). Do you have a reason to believe it would be different?

Comment: The java.io.File class is obsolete.  It doesn’t report errors as well as the more modern java.nio.file package does.  That said, if basic system commands are hanging, I don’t have much confidence that any of the system calls used by any part of Java SE will work any better. but it’s worth trying.

Comment: @VGR It is not obsolete, and changing it will not solve this problem. Th  problem is the bad NFS mount, and *nothing* will solve it. This is why applications never use shared drives directly.

Comment: @user207421 From [the documentation of java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html): “The `java.nio.file` package defines interfaces and classes for the Java virtual machine to access files, file attributes, and file systems. This API may be used to overcome many of the limitations of the `java.io.File` class.”  Feel free to use a different word than ‘obsolete’ if you like, but the File class is ancient and java.nio.file is its superior replacement.